# Multithreading: tkinter mainloop not in main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I was wondering if there was a way to run the tkinter mainloop on a separate thread (not the mainthread) so that the terminal is "free".

Let's say we have a simple GUI:

```
import tkinter as tk       

class Application(tk.Frame):              
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)   
        self.grid()                       
        self.createWidgets()

    def printHello(self):
        print("Hello")

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit',
            command=self.quit)            
        self.quitButton.grid(row=1,column=0)    
        self.printButton = tk.Button(self, text='Print',command=lambda: self.printHello())         
        self.printButton.grid(row=1,column=1) 
app = Application()                        
app.master.title('Sample application')     
app.mainloop()
```

**Observed behavior**: if I run this file using the terminal in PyCharm (let's say) using: `python application.py`, the terminal is then "frozen"/"occupied" by the tkinter mainloop and I am not able to type anything in the terminal.

**Desired behavior**: if I run the gui file with `python application.py`, the terminal is "free" such that it is able to take in additional commands.

I'm aware that `python application.py &` is supposed to free up the terminal but that hasn't worked for me. I'm not very experienced with threading or GUI processes but is there a way to run the tkinter mainloop in a different process / thread so that the terminal will be "free"?

Comment: Try using `pythonw`:  `pythonw application.py`

Comment: but is there a way to manually implement the threading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the threading module to run the GUI in a background thread while using the terminal in the main thread.

Try this code. It will start the GUI then allow input from the terminal.

```
import tkinter as tk       
import threading

class Application(tk.Frame):              
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)   
        self.grid()                       
        self.createWidgets()

    def printHello(self):
        print("Hello")

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit',
            command=self.quit) # exits background (gui) thread
        self.quitButton.grid(row=1,column=0)    
        self.printButton = tk.Button(self, text='Print',command=lambda: self.printHello())         
        self.printButton.grid(row=1,column=1) 

def runtk():  # runs in background thread
    app = Application()                        
    app.master.title('Sample application')     
    app.mainloop()
    
thd = threading.Thread(target=runtk)   # gui thread
thd.daemon = True  # background thread will exit if main thread exits
thd.start()  # start tk loop

while True:  # run in main thread
   x = input("Enter a value or Q to quit: ")
   if x.lower() == 'q':
      exit()
   print('You entered', x)
```